# Complex SQL Query to delete with an IN statement

Tags: sql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have a very big problem with Data Rows, where I get up to 1k Rows, when there should be just 8, and I came with a SQL Query that gets me (I think) all the rows that should be deleted, its like so...

Edit: Also There's no PKEY thats why the duplicate

```
select  a1.ID, a1.serie, a1.tienda, a1.numtransa, a1.sistema, a1.factura, a1.jfecha, a1.codart from posmov a1
inner join posmov a2
on a1.tienda = a2.tienda
and a1.numtransa = a2.numtransa
and a1.sistema= a2.sistema
and a1.factura =a2.factura
and a1.jfecha = a2.jfecha
and a1.codart = a2.codart
and a1.serie =a2.serie
and a1.ID > a2.ID;
```

But when I want to delete them adding to the last query

```
delete from posmov
where ID  in ( LAST QUERY);
```

I get ..

```
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

Can someone enlight me, if there's an easier way, to or do the query, or actually delete duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Just select the ID in your query, whenever you use `IN` you can list values  ('1','2','3') or you can select a single field from a subquery, but not multiple fields:

```
delete from posmov
where ID  in (
              select  a1.ID
              inner join posmov a2
              on a1.tienda = a2.tienda
              and a1.numtransa = a2.numtransa
              and a1.sistema= a2.sistema
              and a1.factura =a2.factura
              and a1.jfecha = a2.jfecha
              and a1.codart = a2.codart
              and a1.serie =a2.serie
              and a1.ID > a2.ID)
```

Alternatively, you could use `EXISTS`:

```
delete from posmov
where EXISTS ( LAST QUERY);
```

Comment: Note that the `EXISTS` statement is almost always much faster than `IN`